# How do I get a deployment slot's MSI to work with Azure SQL external provider users?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

We have an azure sql database and an external user that points to an azure AD group. We have a user in that group that is the MSI for the "Production" slot.

I enabled the MSI for a deployment slot and added it to the AD group but it gets a login failed message that I typically see when the principal doesn't have access to the database.

I initially thought it might be because of time to sync the AD permissions but it has been over 3 hours and it still doesn't to be picking up permissions.

When I swap the slots, the code that was in the slot works just fine.

Am I missing a step? What can I try to diagnose what's going on?

Comment: Reset the AD group in `Active Directory admin`, will it work?